# Doubts about a Python Webserver

Tags: python, webserver

I've a project which I developed a code to capture a temperature in some sensors and displaying a temperature to people, in fact I've a database (txt archive) whose was readed in a webserver to people in same network, now I've to improve this webpage (with some graphics, analitycs and etc) .
Someone has a tip to improve that? or begin a new project with a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For sure, if you are beginner in python then you should try do it as simple as it can be for example using Flask, all information you can find here: http://flask.pocoo.org/
Also if you want to write serious web page which contain advanced backend then you probably need Django: https://www.djangoproject.com/

**EDIT:**
I see that you already have some application that probably contain data from sensors, then it is good idea to re use it as a module for your web-service .